# Add-user script not working, running: read $user; useradd $user

Tags: bash

I've been trying to write a script that adds a non-root user. Is it possible to use variables and adduser to do it? I've tried just `adduser bob` and it works perfectly fine, so why does adduser $user return `adduser: Only one or two names allowed.`?

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Do you want to add a non-root user? [y/N]' answer
case "${answer}" in
    [yY]|[yY][eE][sS])
    echo -e "What will the username be?"
    read $user
    adduser $user;;
    [nN]|[nN][oO])
    echo "Skipping";;
esac
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is you are not adding anyone. In your script you have:

```
read $user
```

it should be

```
read user
```

Also note the correct command is `useradd`. `adduser`, if it exists, is generally just a link to `useradd`.

Comment: In Debian or Ubuntu, `adduser` is not just a link to `useradd`. `adduser` is friendlier front end script than `useradd`.

Comment: "useradd is native binary compiled with the system. But, adduser is a perl script which uses useradd binary in back-end.
adduser is more user friendly and interactive than its back-end useradd. There's no difference in features provided."